# C++ type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter

Tags: c++

Ok so I have this code below and when I execute it I get the following error:

```
type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’
     vector<s> v;
```

```
template <class T>
class A {
public:
    struct s{T x;};
};

template <class T>
class B: public A<T> {
public:
    using A<T>::s;
    vector<s> v;
};
```

Can someone please explain the problem.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that the compiler doesn't know whether `s` is a type or a value.  This is the case where you add `typename` or `template`, but neither of those worked when I tested.  Using the full type directly in the `vector` [does work](https://godbolt.org/g/hLX9mj) however:

```
template <class T>
class B: public A<T> {
public:
    using A<T>::s;
    std::vector<typename A<T>::s> v;
};
```

(Edit) Kept playing with it because why not, and of course `typename` was needed in the one place I didn't trying it: the `using` line.  The following code [also works](https://godbolt.org/g/MNnbny).

```
template <class T>
class B: public A<T> {
public:
    using typename A<T>::s;
    std::vector<s> v;
};
```

Comment: this typename requirement always stumps me

Comment: Cool, it works. Interesting, when I do `using A::someobject` I don't need the typename. Looks like the typename is required when you use some defined structure.